# Sending SMS messages from Python for personal use

Tags: python, sms

I'm looking to be able to write a Python script that will send an SMS message to my phone under certain circumstances.

To do that, it looks like I need some kind of online SMS API service. I did try signing up with TextMagic, which worked well and did what I needed, but they have since cancelled my account: it turns out they only want to deal with business users and when they realised I was using their service for personal use they booted me out.

I have also attempted to sign up with FireText, but I'm not hopeful, it looks from their website as if they only want to deal with business users too.

Does anyone know of a service that will deal with personal users? I will not be using it heavily, so ideally a service where you simply pay a small fee per message sent (I really don't mind if the price per message is uncompetitive) and there is no monthly subscription fee.

Or is there any other way to send an SMS message from Python without such a service?

I will only ever need to send SMS messages to a UK number, so as long as the service works in the UK I'm not worried about global coverage.

***Update 5 February 2024:***

After a couple of unsuccessful attempts to sign up with various services, I finally settled on Twilio. Their prices are reasonable (at least for light use, not sure if they're competitive if you're sending thousands of messages a day), they are happy to have personal users, and the messages are delivered more or less instantly.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and found this site: Pilvo.
easy to use with its python libraries and you pay $0.0330/sms for message in uk

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to sign up for it though I have a nasty feeling they also may not welcome personal users. I was told I'd failed their risk assessment and my account was put on hold. I filled in a form to get my account taken off hold, so fingers crossed.

Comment: Well it looks like they don't want personal users either. They've replied to me now and told me they don't want me as a customer. On the plus side, I think I may have found another service now: Text Local. They even have a place in the sign-up where you can specify if you're a business or personal customer. I've managed to sign up for them and even successfully sent a couple of text messages. They were rather slow to be delivered (about 10 min), but at least they'll let me be a customer.

Comment: A little update on Text Local: the system does work, and they haven't kicked me out for being a personal user, but it seems that the slow delivery is an unavoidable feature of their system. I've had a bit of back and forth with their technical support about this, but apparently there is no way I can get the messages delivered faster.

This will do for now: mostly my messages aren't that time critical that a 10 minute delay would be a huge problem. But I think my search for a better service will continue in the background, as it would be nice to find a faster sevice.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the PyTextNow module (https://pypi.org/project/PyTextNow/). It is an unofficial module for [textnow.com](https://textnow.com). Textnow.com is a free service that gives you a VOIP number to use through their website, or through the app. But with the PyTextNow module, you give it your CSRF token and cookie, and then you can use the texting features through a Python script to send/receive texts.

Just keep in mind that it is an unofficial module, and it is probably against TextNow's terms of service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had a look at that, but it looks like it's no longer being maintained, which rather puts me off:
https://github.com/leogomezz4t/PyTextNow_API

Comment: @AdamJacobs Yes, its not even working for me any more - I read somewhere TextNow may have purposely broke it. Plus, they (the people putting it up) were facing DMCA take downs. Looks like it may be dead... Twilio is decent, they are open to hobby users.

Answer (score 0):

first install
pip install pywhatkit

import pywhatkit

print("\n")
print("Type a number to message:")
number = input()

print("\n")
print("Type a message:")
message = input()

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(number, message, 10)

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+910123456789", "Hi", 13, 30, 15, True, 2)

pywhatkit.sendwhats_image("AB123CDEFGHijklmn", "Images/Hello.png", "Hello")

pywhatkit.sendwhats_image("+910123456789", "Images/Hello.png")

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group("AB123CDEFGHijklmn", "Hey All!", 0, 0)

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group_instantly("AB123CDEFGHijklmn", "Hey All!")

pywhatkit.playonyt("PyWhatKit")